# Login to the facebook using omniouth-facebook and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise

I am using devise gem for Sign in and sign up . Now i wanna include facebook and google  login in my app . As I am newbie to Rails please suggest me the best method to facebook and google login , I have tried so many methods but they didnt worked please give me an working example. Thanks in advance.